# What is better for? Updating Old blog vs Starting New Blog

Tags: seo, google

I had a technology blog like Labnol. It has around 50 posts. To be honest, those are **not high quality posts**. It just has around 300-500 words and their are very **general posts like** "Top 10 WordPress Plugins", "Best Android Apps", "How to Download a Whole Website" etc.

I stopped updating that blog just 1 and half year back. That time it had around 2000-4000 monthly organic traffic.

Not it has just around 300 monthly organic traffic.

Now this is the question.

I have plan to start a technology blog again with better quality.

**For better SEO**, should I start a new blog or should I start adding new posts to old blog?

Comment: Should not matter.

Comment: @closetnoc What did you mean by "Should not matter." ?

Comment: There is no problem updating and using your old domain. In fact, domain age should be the only real benefit. Otherwise, if you really want to use a new domain, that should be fine too. Really, short of the domain age, there will really be no difference.

Comment: You may also want to consider any old links that may be of value. If the link profile is nothing to write home about, that should not really matter either.

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc  . Assume that I go with old website. As I said old posts are not quality. But spending around 40 hours I can update all posts with little bit more details. Will it help to get more SEO traffic for old posts also? I mean considering traffic because 40 hours mean huge time?

Comment: Updating old content is always a good idea unless you are writing about the War of 1812. The top 10 list style posts are popular in search, but personally annoying to me. Sooooo cliche'. You can keep them and update them to retain your traffic. I have to having read a few though for stuff like data mining. I guess they are a part of reality, though, also a part of homogenizing the web into a "me too" echo chamber of no particular value. Perhaps you can update them with solid technical reasons why one is better than the next and add real detail. That would be good!

Comment: I wrote my last comment last night to discover that they took my line down for maintenance. Sorry for the delay/downtime. Cheers!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60944/discussion-between-damith-ruwan-and-closetnoc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your old blog got general quality post but not done cheap or poor SEO then it's worth sticking to old blog and try and improve it by having better quality posts.

**Keeping Old Blog:**
Slowly you can work on new quality posts and if you feel old posts may not be of best quality then you can redirect to relevant new one and take them down. Also, note that the age of the domain will be also a ranking factor (Not significant though).

**Starting Fresh:**
The only time starting fresh new blog/domain is recommended if you feel poor SEO was done on the old blog and it may impact getting good ranking for the effort you will put in.